# Conexion class not found

Tags: java, netbeans, sqlite

I'm trying to make a connection to sqlite from netbeans but it doesn't get my conexion class

this is my code:

```
   package Petrocabimas_App;

import Petrocabimas_app.Login;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Conexion {


 Connection conn= null;
  public static void main(String args[]) {
 Login log= new Login();
log.setVisible (true);
}

public static Connection ConnecrDb(){


try{
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
 Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:F:/Petrocabimas/APLICACIÓN AVISO CAMBIO/Petrocabimas_App/Petrocabimas.db");
System.out.println( "Connection Established");
return conn;
   }catch (Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   return null;

   }

}
}
```

And this is my error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Petrocabimas_app/Conexion (wrong name: Petrocabimas_App/Conexion)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: Petrocabimas_app.Conexion.  Program will exit.
    Exception in thread "main" 
    Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1

Comment: Check your package declaration. Specifically, should "App" really be upper-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at logs

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Petrocabimas_app/Conexion
```

but

```
package Petrocabimas_App;
```

update class path at place where your call Connexion class